# how to create link for the first letter of each string in a sentence in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Say i have a variable
`<wish>Hi jony</wish>`
I have to traverse the wish element and i have to create link for first letter of the string in the element.
output should be`<a href="#H">H</a>
<a href="#j">j</a>.`

Comment: <xsl:for-each select='tokenize($keyword, ",")'> <xsl:element name="a"> <xsl:attribute name="href"> <xsl:value-of select='substring(.,1,1)'/> </xsl:attribute> #<xsl:value-of select='substring(.,1,1)'/> </xsl:element> </xsl:for-each> I did this i got the out put <a href="%0A      #E">E</a><a href="%0A      #J">J</a>. how to get only # in value for href ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're going for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wish">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="link-first-letters">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>            
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="link-first-letters">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>

        <xsl:variable name="first-letter" select="substring($text, 1, 1)"/>

        <a href="#{$first-letter}"><xsl:value-of select="$first-letter"/></a>


        <xsl:if test="contains($text, ' ')">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="link-first-letters">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <wish>Hi jony</wish>
</root>
```

it produces the following output:

```
<root>
    <wish><a href="#H">H</a> <a href="#j">j</a></wish>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive template to split the string, then build the  elements. Here are the templates you can apply:

```
  <xsl:template match="Wish">
    <xsl:call-template name="links">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="links">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="newtext" select="concat(normalize-space($text), ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newtext, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="normalize-space(substring-after($newtext, ' '))" />
    <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">#<xsl:value-of select="substring($first, 1, 1)"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($first, 1, 1)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="links">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$remaining" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Cleaned up and simplified it would look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($keyword,' ')">
    <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring(.,1,1)"/>
    <a href="{concat('#',$letter)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>
    </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Based on your use of tokenize, I'm assuming you are using XSLT 2.0 which obviates the need for harpo's recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="wish">
     <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\W+')">
      <xsl:variable name="vFirst" select="substring(.,1,1)"/>
      <a href="#{$vFirst}"><xsl:value-of select="$vFirst"/></a>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<wish>Hi jony</wish>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<a href="#H">H</a>
<a href="#j">j</a>
```

**Do note**: No use of `concat()` is required.

Comment: Dimitre, your markdown for SO is generated from XSLT, isn't it.

Comment: "Markdown" is the name of the format used in answer submissions.

Comment: @harpo: I still don't quite understand this comment. To format code (including XML or XSLT), just select this code and press the `{}` button.

Comment: I was being a little tongue-in-cheek.  Your answers follow a very regular template, and clearly you have some automation for checking inputs and outputs.  As you are the consummate master of XSLT, logically one would conclude that you use a transform to format your answers. :)

Comment: @harpo: No, I do this manually. In fact writing in a specific format is easier to get accustomed to that remembering a password. I also (still) think manually :) Joking aside, you are right that there are some "templates" and best practices for producing an answer.